# Printing from a remote windows computer on a printer connected to a MacBook Air

Tags: windows, printing

We have a consultant who has a MacBook Air. He connects that to one of our printers via USB. The Mac recognizes the printer and we can print from his documents etc. He then remotes to his office computer which is a Windows PC. He needs to print stuff from his office computer on the printer that is connected to his Mac. The documents will not print. We can't get the remote computer to recognize the printer that is connected to the Mac. (It actually did work for a while, I have no idea how we got it working, but now that it has stopped again, he is getting mad at us for not being able to get it to work.) I have spent hours on his Mac, trying to get the printing working and can't.

Comment: How does he remote-access his Windows PC?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences on the mac, click on the `sharing` icon under Internet and Wireless. Highlight `Printer Sharing` and select the printer from the Printers: check box. Make sure Users "Everyone" is set to "Can Print"

You should be able to see the share from the other computer.